# Tracking using hybris plugin

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to perform ecommerce tracking in a hybris site. Will it be possible for non web developers to do it? I want to track add to cart, remove from cart events. I want this to happen using Google analytics and Google tag manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible to do. You need to modified project.properties file of the yacceleratorstorefront and or yb2bacceleratorstorefront.

```
google.analytics.tracking.id=trackIDHere
google.analytics.tracking.id.YourStoreHere.local=trackIDHere
```

Once that is done you need to have a googleAnalytics.tag file placed within your storefront. YourStoreFront/web/webroot/WEB-INF/tags/shared/analytics/googleAnalytics.tag

Comment: Thank You!!!Will all the details get tracked with these two lines of code.I implemented universal google analytics but in googleAnalytics.tag I see that it has code in classic google analytics format.So how should I proceed further.

Comment: I installed googletagmanager plugin provided by hybris for mysite.But that also seems not working.Since the googleAnalytics.tag containing code of classic google analytics be a reason for it not to be working.

Comment: As far as I know, I may be wrong I haven't touched much on the analytics, it has to be the classic format. I'm sure you can play around with it and try. You'll quickly know if you need the classic format.

Also I do believe it once you've got the above in the properties file and the tag file in place it should be it.

Answer (score 0):

The following extension uses Google Tag Manager. It also includes instructions around the implementation as well as the GTM container that can be imported to your Google Tag Manager account.

https://www.hybris.com/en/products/extensions/google-analytics